# Is Ohm's law valid in AC circuits?

Tags: circuit-analysis, electromagnetic

I am confused over this and I’m hoping for clarification.

By Ohm's law we can compute the resistance of a circuit as V/I. In the case of two sinusoids we have sin(x) / cos(x) or something like that. Doesn’t this give a sinusoidal resistance? I don’t understand this because resistance is a set value. A 100 ohm resistor is a 100 ohm resistor. Does the division of the sinusoids always result in a constant term?

Comment: Ohms law ALWAYS applies.  Even in AC circuits.   Keen observation on your part however.   But you may regret you just opened pandoras box of circuit analysis.   The key concept you will need to understand is PHASORS -- This is necessary to really compute AC stuff.   Not "Phasors" like from star trek.. This is real.   (Well, and imaginary...)    You'll see...     https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/accircuits/phasors.html

Comment: *But in the case of two sinusoids we have sin(x) / cos(x)* Is that possible in case of a resistor? Can the voltage be a sin(x) while the current is cos(x)? In a resistor, voltage and current must have the same shape. When talking about capacitors and inducors, indeed we could get sin(x) / cos(x).

Comment: AC/DC linear networks.

Comment: Sin divided by cos gives tan and that has major and infinite discontinuities hence, we find a way around that problem by shifting one of the two by 90 degrees. This aligns them and the result is a constant that we dimension in ohms. But, we also put a j in front of those ohms to signify our little cheat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ohm's Law, in its standard formulation, applies to specifically those circuit elements which we consider resistors (or ohmic) - the voltage and current are instantaneously proportional at all times with the relation \$V(t) = I(t)R\$.

This excludes an element with out-of-phase voltage and current from the standard Ohm's Law formulation. Because its voltage and current are out of phase, it is simply not a resistor and not handled by the equation.

However, when discussing *linear* circuitry (i.e. circuits composed of resistors, capacitors, and inductors) operating at *one* frequency, it is possible to represent sines and cosines as complex numbers instead. This is called *phasor analysis*.

In your example of voltage as sin(x) and current as cos(x), we can suppose that \$x = \omega t\$ (i.e. the frequency is \$\omega/2\pi\$ Hz). Then, the voltage is -1j volts (where j is the square root of -1) and the current is 1 ampere.

We can then apply an extended form of Ohm's Law and say that the *impedance* of the circuit is \$Z = V/I = -1j \,[\Omega]\$.

This formulation can be extended to other phases (not just 90 degrees); for example a resistor and inductor in parallel may have an impedance of 0.4j + 0.6 (at some fixed frequency). Of course, this extended phasor formulation agrees with the standard Ohm's Law formulation whenever the circuit is purely resistive.

Answer (score 2):

Ohm's Law always holds, but you must apply it properly. Ohm's Law describes the relationship between voltage, current, and resistance for an **ideal** resistor. The "voltage" **must** be the voltage across the resistor and the current **must** be the current through the resistor, and the current must be defined as entering the resistor terminal that is assumed to have the higher voltage.

Ohm's Law describes instantaneous behavior. There is no dependence on frequency or time.

Answer (score 1):

The current in an AC circuit is a sinusoid the voltage is a sinusoid. Current is voltage divided by resistance, if you divide a sinusoidal voltage by a constant resistance you get a sinusoidal result.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

First, make sure you understand the difference between instantanoeus quantities and phasor quantities. Secondly, it depends on what we speciically mean by Ohm's law, and where (in which device and under which condition) we apply it.

1. If by Ohm's law you mean that instantaneous voltage \$v(t)\$ across a two-terminal device is directly proportional to the instantaneous current \$i(t)\$ through the device, which implies the static or DC resistance \$R\$ is constant in the equation \$v(t) = R \, i(t)\$, then it applies to all resistors/wires/devices that have a constant \$R\$ (yes, that's redundant), whether they operate with constant voltage and current or with sinusoidal voltage and current. It does not apply to inductors nor capacitors, though we could define their static/DC resistance as the ratio of instantaneous voltage to instantaneous current, but then such ratio (the resistance) wouldn't be constant, meaning Ohm's law is not obeyed in those devices.
2. If by Ohm's law you mean that in a two-terminal device operating in sinusoidal steady-state conditions, the phasor voltage \$\tilde V\$ across the device is equal to the phasor current \$\tilde I\$ through the device times the (complex) impedance \$\hat Z\$ of the device, then it applies to any network/circuit consisting exclusively of constant-resistance resistors, constant-inductance inductors, constant-capacitance capacitors, magnetically coupled inductors of constant mutual inductance, and ideal transformers. It doesn't really apply to ideal independent or dependent sources.